# "Server is unwilling to process the request" when creating an AD group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to create a Powershell script to create a new group ("TestUsers") under the Users container in my domain controller.The domain controller runs on a 2008 Server R2 64bit VM.

My code is like this:

```
#  Group Types in AD
#
# -2147483646 Global security group
# -2147483644 Domain local security group
# -2147483640 Universal security group

$groupName = "TestUsers"
$groupType = -2147483646

$root = [ADSI]""
$rootdn = $root.distinguishedName
$UsersNode = [ADSI]("LDAP://localhost:389/cn=Users,"+$rootdn)
$UsersNode.Create("group", "cn=" + $groupName)
$usersNode.Put("groupType", $groupType)    
$UsersNode.Put("sAMAccountName", $groupName)
$UsersNode.SetInfo()
```

When executing `$UsersNode.SetInfo()` the script throws the following error:

```
Exception calling "SetInfo" with "0" argument(s): "The server is unwilling to process the request.
"
At line:1 char:19
+ $UsersNode.SetInfo <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterMethodInvokeTI
```

I'm running the script on the domain controller itself, logged in as domain administrator account i.e. mydomain\Administrator

Tried also different group types without any luck.

I'm a newbie with AD scripting so I have pretty much followed below article.

http://geekseat.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/script-of-the-day-creating-ad-groups-without-qad-cmdlets/

As in the article above, I would not like to install 3rd party cmdlets.

Thanks.

Comment: From what JP says you may need to tweak your script but I though I'd say something about the (somewhat emotional!) error message "Server is unwilling to process the request".

I used to get that intermittently, it was a temporary issue and retrying the script\action would work. We thought it might be related to replication but never got to the bottom of the issue.

sometimes it seemed AD would just ignore us! :-)

Comment: I carry around a stick with a nail through it for unwilling computers...

Answer (score 2):

You just forget that the group object (here `$CreatedGroup`) is returned by the creation in the users node. you have to add attributes on the groupe object.

Here is the solution :

```
#  Group Types in AD
#
# -2147483646 Global security group
# -2147483644 Domain local security group
# -2147483640 Universal security group

$groupName = "TestUsers"
$groupType = -2147483646

$root = [ADSI]""
$rootdn = $root.distinguishedName
$UsersNode = [ADSI]("LDAP://localhost:389/cn=Users,"+$rootdn)
$CreatedGrp = $UsersNode.Create("group", "cn=" + $groupName)
$CreatedGrp.Put("groupType", $groupType)  
$CreatedGrp.Put("sAMAccountName", $groupName)
$CreatedGrp.SetInfo()
```

Be careful to run it as administrator.

---

If you are using Windows server 2008 R2 you can use Cmdlet from the ActiveDirectory module (shortest, more readable)

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
New-ADGroup -Name $groupName -SamAccountName $groupName -GroupCategory Security -GroupScope Global -DisplayName $groupName -Path "CN=Users" + $rootdn
```